# A Simple Guide to Long Polling in 5 Minutes example not working

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Is there are any errors on this code ?
[The Example here](http://www.screenr.com/SNH)

I try to make the same example but it didn't working well

I wanna make a real time notification from Database if any body can help me on that by send tome tutorials or anything help

Note : i work on localhost with wamp server

## HTML

### index.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
            var timestamp = null;
    function waitForMsg () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "getData.php?timestamp="+timestamp,
            async: true,
            cache : false,
            success : function (data){
                var json = eval('(' + data + ')');
                if (json['msg'] != "") {
                    alert(json['msg']);
                }

                timestamp = json['timestamp'];
                setTimeOut("waitForMsg()" , 1000);
            },
            erorr : function  (XMLHttpRequest,textStatus, erorrThrown) {
                alert("erorr :" + textStatus + "(" + erorrThrown + ")");
                setTimeOut("waitForMsg()", 15000);
            }

        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        waitForMsg();
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

## PHP

### getData.php

```
<?php 
$filename = dirname(__FLIE__)."/data.txt";
$lastmodif = isset($_GET['timestamp']) ? $_GET['timestamp'] : 0;
$currentmodif = filemtime($filename);

while($currentmodif <= $lastmodif){
    usleep(10000);
    clearstatcache();
    $currentmodif = filemtime($filename);
}

$response = array();
$response['msg'] = file_get_contents($filename);
$response['timestamp'] = currentmodif();
echo json_encode($response);
```

?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$response['timestamp'] = currentmodif();
```

should be

```
$response['timestamp'] = $currentmodif;
```

currentmodif is a variable not a function.

Comment: `$response['timestamp'] = $currentmodif;`